# Use underscore hidden divs and no script templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I want to use underscore hidden divs and not script templates, ie, instead of this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="fooTemplate">
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
    <p>
        <img src='<%= img %>' width='95' height='150'>
        <br/><br/>
        by <strong><%= autor %></strong>
        <br/><br/>
        <i><%= date %></i>
        <br/><br/>
        <%= description %>
    </p>
 </script>
```

Use this:

```
 <div id="fooTemplate" style="display:none">
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
    <p>
        <img src='<%= img %>' width='95' height='150'>
        <br/><br/>
        by <strong><%= autor %></strong>
        <br/><br/>
        <i><%= date %></i>
        <br/><br/>
        <%= description %>
    </p>
 </div>
```

If I get the variable and use html () or .text () I get the following and have the following problems:

.html()

```
<h2>&lt;%= title %&gt;</h2>
<p>
    <img src="<%= img %>" height="150" width="95">
    <br><br>
    by <strong>&lt;%= autor %&gt;</strong>
    <br><br>
    <i>&lt;%= date %&gt;</i>
    <br><br>
    &lt;%= description %&gt;
</p>
```

.text()

```
<%= title %>

    by <%= autor %>

    <%= date %>

    <%= description %>
```

with .text () html I lose but prints the value of variables and html () does not catch me the syntax to print values ​​underscore. I've solved a replace as follows:

```
$("#fooTemplate").html().replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
```

Any other solution to solve the problem or other form of charging a hidden section as a template to underscore?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use the script template...?

Comment: I want clean code, just html and js and css files. Templates for the rows of columns that have in charge tmpl files. But in this case is to show an insertion or modification and have labels with messages of spring.

Comment: But Underscore templates are rarely valid HTML so browsers will often "correct" them and make a mess of things; also the browser is going to try to load your `<img>` and pollute your server logs with useless nonsense. If you want "clean" code then compile your Underscore templates on the server and send them to the browser as a pile of JavaScript functions.

Comment: I had not thought about the problem with such images. I will try to send the template from the server. Thank you very much.